# Change value in a nested NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary to which I want to change the value of an element.

```
//My dictionary:

{
    objectId = 8ED998yWd1;
    cardInfo =     {
        state = published; //THIS!
        price = 40;
        color = red;
        }   
};
```

I have tried several ways, but the value does not change, like this:

```
[dictionary setObject:@"reserved" forKey:@"state"]; //nope
```

or this:

```
[dictionary setValue:@"reserved" forKeyPath:@"cardInfo.state"]; //nope
```

or that:

```
[[dictionary objectForKey:@"cardInfo"] setObject:@"reserved" forKey:@"state"]; //no
```

and this:

```
[dictionary setObject:@"reserved" forKey:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"cardInfo"] objectForKey:@"state"]];
```

How can I change the object "state" from "published" to "reserved"?

Thank you!

Comment: How is this `NSMutableDictionary` being generated? JSON? By hand?

Comment: Is the inner `cardInfo` dictionary also a mutable dictionary?

Comment: I take the file from JSON. I found the problem, in the previous controller dictionary was not mutable. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that both `dictionary` and `cardInfo` are `NSDictionary` instances:

You could get a mutable copy of the nested dictionary, modify the appropriate value, and write the modified dictionary back into the "top level" dictionary, like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [dictionary mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = [dictionary[@"cardInfo"] mutableCopy];
innerDict[@"state"] = @"reserved";
mutableDict[@"cardInfo"] = innerDict;
dictionary = [mutableDict copy];
```

I guess you *could* squeeze that in one line, but it would be one ugly line.

**Edit:**

If both the outer and inner dictionary were already `mutable` that would simplify things a bit, of course:

```
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = dictionary[@"cardInfo"];
innerDict[@"state"] = @"reserved";
dictionary[@"cardInfo"] = innerDict;
```

Comment: In your last bit of code, there is no reason to reassign `innerDict`. In fact, if the whole thing already consists of mutable dictionaries you can just do `dictionary[@"cardInfo"][@"state"] = @"reserved";`.

Comment: Thanks but I have always the same type of log "[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96f947b9c0"

Comment: I found the problem, in the previous controller dictionary was not mutable. Sorry.